# Jasmine toThrow does not work even though an error is thrown

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine

This code fails even though an error is thrown.

```
it('should throw error when foo config value is falsey', (done) => {
  const config = { foo: null, bar: 'some-name' };
  expect(quux.withConfig(config).load('*', (err, inst) => { done(); })).toThrow();
});
```

I've also tried this

```
it('should throw error when foo config value is falsey', (done) => {
  const config = { foo: null, bar: 'some-name' };
  expect(SelfServiceCompletedJobStore.withConfig(config).load('*', (err, inst) => { })).toThrow();
  done();
});
```

Error Message:

```
should throw error when foo config value is falsey
  - Error: Requires a non-empty foo:String
```

Answer (score 3):

you should be passing a function into the expect(...). The following code:

```
expect(quux.withConfig(config).load('*', (err, inst) => { done();    })).toThrow();
```

is trying to actually to pass the result of the call into expect(...),

Use an anonymous function instead:

```
expect(function(){ 
    quux.withConfig(config).load('*', (err, inst) => { done(); });   
}).toThrow();
```